# Chrome freezes when I search facebook in google.com, using chrome

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, virus, malware, facebook

I search facebook in google.com, in chrome and the results appear instantly. But, chrome freezes for 5-6 seconds after the results are displayed. This happens ALL the time. What could be the reason for this ? Does this happen to anyone else ? It only freezes the first time. does not happen when i search again in same window. If I clear history and search again in same window, no problems again.

I was thinking it could be some malware in my system that monitors browser searches for chrome. Also, my antivirus (which is password protected) was shutdown twice in a period of 5 days. BUT, this facebook problem started a long time ago - 1-2 months.

Comment: Are you using the site: tag? What do you mean you search facebook in google.com

Comment: go to google.com. Then search for facebook.

Comment: Why not just go to facebook.com?

Comment: @BradPatton - yes, thats what i always do. but i need news about FB. I want to know why this freezing happens.

Comment: Oh I get it now. Does that happen for other search terms? Just FB. How about in other browsers? Any difference between doing the search in the command bar and on the page? What OS are you using? There's not a lot of info in your question and it seems like a pretty specific issue.